# Increase "label" with 1 in each "button" click

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I need help! I want to make a label that increase 1 by 1 with each click from a button.

So when I press the button the label should change to 1 then 2 then 3 then 4 and so on.

How do I do that with swift in Xcode?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like,

Declare one variable

```
var counter = 0
```

Now create one action for button click,

```
@IBAction func btnClick(sender : UIButton) {
     counter += 1
     labelCount.text = String(counter)
     print(counter)
}
```